# Warning while Debugging java code

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, jvm

I was debugging my java code in Intellij IDEA and I encountered following warning. I have debugged my code a lot of times but never saw the below dialog box.

[image]

Any idea why this warning is shown and why did it suspend the JVM?

Comment: How much CPU% it eats while in suspended mode?

Comment: I think this is when you have code suspended on a breakpoint, then change the code and then try and debug again. Check to see if you have more than one debugging session open

Comment: The blamb on the low left corner shows you that you can ignore this open dialog.

Comment: @RNJ you are right. It seems two instances of debugger were running and I had changed the code in between. Tx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the sake of completing this question. Above situation occurs when you have two or more instances of your program being debugged. As I had changed my code in between IDE asked whether the edited class needs to be reloaded or existing class has to be used.

You can either close the older instance or select yes to reload the classes. IDE warns of suspending the JVM but nothing like that happened in my case. On selecting yes debugging happened just fine.